# No source available in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gdb, bare-metal

I'm using GDB 7.3 in Eclipse.  It's connecting to a GDBServer.
When I launch the debugger in Eclipse I get:

> No source available for "main() at 0x101250"

I'm compiling with the optimizer turned off and the debug flag set to max:

> -O0 -g3

I see the debug symbols when I run:

> ./powerpc-unknown-eabi-objdump.exe -g | grep debug

GDB 8.1 is able to find the sources.  However, I can't use it due to incompatibilities with the GDBServer I'm connecting to :(

Edit:
I have added the source in the "Source" tab in the "Debug Configuration." I've even added the source manually in the GDB terminal aka "Debugger Console" using the following:

> directory /path/to/src/
>
> Source directories searched: /path/to/src/:$cdir:$cwd

Comment: I asume you are using eclipse to build your program, right? 
Maybe you have to add the source location at tab "Source" in your "Debug configuration".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have added the source in the "Source" tab in the "Debug Configuration."  I've even added the command in the GDB terminal aka "Debugger Console" using the following: "directory /path/to/src/"  I've updated my question to illustrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who have this issue in the future.

The problem comes from using a new version of GCC (GCC 8.1) and an older version of GDB (GDB 7.3)

GCC is putting out a new version of debug symbols that the old version GDB does not know how to deal with.  I added flags to GCC to produce older dwarf symbols:

> -ggdb -gdwarf-3

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) is the documentation for those flags

Comment: I think you only need `-gdwarf3`. Help for `-ggdb` says:  _Produce debugging information for use by GDB. This means to use the most expressive format available (DWARF, stabs, or the native format if neither of those are supported), including GDB extensions if at all possible._

Comment: Interesting fact, a guy named Thomas Schmid was my embedded instructor.  That is the class that made me want to be an embedded engineer.

Comment: Nice, but I'm sorry, it wasn't me.